# remote desktop connection - similar to team viewer

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, remote-management

I have a few different Desktop versions of Ubuntus (13.04, 12.04, Kubuntu,..) on different computers.

I would like to manage all of them on a single computer via remote connection and be able to use GUI programs on the remote computer as team viewer allows.

But, team viewer provides a limited connection time for the free versions. Therefore, I am looking for a substitute that it is easy to install, use, and works fine on different versions of Ubuntu desktops, and freeware.

What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean just the whole desktop view or the single applications view too?

Comment: it does not matter as long as it allows me to access the programs on the remote desktop and easy to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the application [Vinagre](https://projects.gnome.org/vinagre/screenshots.html).

[image: vinagre]

You invoke it from the command line like so:

```
$ vinagre
```

There is also a applet that should be available when you install it so that you can just pick machines that you've bookmarked with it form a pulldown when you add the applet to your toolbar.

Comment: +1. Remmina at http://remmina.sourceforge.net/ is another good alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using VNC, possible tunneled over SSH or through a VPN for security. You will need to run a VNC server on each machine you want to access. The `tightvnc` package contains `vncserver`, this launches an X11 server separate from the one displayed on that computer's monitor, and a VNC server to give you access to it. There is also a package `x11vnc`, it contains a VNC server that will connect to the X11 server already running on the computer, which is much more convenient for screen sharing. `x11vnc` will act like teamviewer.

As for VNC clients, `tightvnc` comes with `vncviewer`. You may also want to try the `vinagre` that slm mentions.

As for other options, X11 forwarding would allow an application to display itself on a different computer, but you can't move the display between different computers, and it has some really crippling performance issues. Many applications now come with a web interface, e.g. some popular bittorrent clients, and this would be most efficient by far if the applications you need support this.