# How can I connect to a Mac OSX Maverick Shared Screen from Fedora 18?

Tags: fedora, vnc

I used to use TigerVNC to connect to a Mac MINI running Mountain Lion from my laptop running Fedora Core 18.  After upgrading the Mac to Maverick, I now get the error "No Matching Security Types"

I've tried every setting I can change through the GUI with the same result.  I have also tried using other free VNC viewers, and still have had no luck.

I know for a fact that Screen Sharing is working, I am able to connect using another Mac.

Is there a way to do this without having to purchase a VNC viewer like RealVNC that I don't know will work?

The other viewers I tried are:

- remmina (only appears to have SSH or SFTP as protocol options)
- NoMachine (only has SSH and NX as options)
- I downloaded gtkvncviewer but it doesn't appear to actually do anything and give no error report

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91811/remote-desktop-connection-similar-to-team-viewer/91815#91815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vinagre](https://projects.gnome.org/vinagre/screenshots.html) appears to work well enough.

[image: vinagre]

You invoke it from the command line like so:

```
$ vinagre
```

There is also a applet that should be available when you install it so that you can just pick machines that you've bookmarked with it form a pulldown when you add the applet to your toolbar.

Comment: I had problems getting `vinagre` to work with a password length of over 8 characters.